# During json decode "Invalid \uXXXX\uXXXX surrogate pair" appears on GAE server, but not on localhost

Tags: json, google-app-engine, utf-8, character-encoding

In my app, I'm running a following command on Python26 locally:

> json.loads('"xxxx \ud83d xxxx"');

And it parses the string no problem.

But once I upload the code to the GAE server, the following error appears:

```
"Invalid \uXXXX\uXXXX surrogate pair"
```

Any suggestions? Could it be because I'm running python2.6 locally, and GAE is running on python2.5?
The string that causes problem is from an API from a well known site, so it's 100% percent valid. How do I force GAE to parse it correctly?

Comment: It may be a 2.5 vs. 2.6 thing. Try deploying to Python 2.7

Comment: I guess so, but Python2.7 is still experimental. If the json is correct (and I'm sure it is), there has to be a way to properly parse it in 2.5...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO the json implementations on your computer and on GAE differ. [Here](http://simplejson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/simplejson/decoder.py) is a simplejson implementation which tells you what are the conditions to get the error.

Update: It looks like you have to prefix your string with **u** like `u"xxxx \ud83d xxxx"`

Comment: Thanks, your link to simplejson implementation helped. It seems that GAE is running on a different UTF-8 implementation than localhost (UCS-4 system), and this character is not allowed there, or sth.

Comment: What I did was not nice, but I just copied the whole simplejson module, and modified the test that caused the error to just skip the characters.

Comment: @Merlin This is what I end up doing too to ensure that production and test use the same code base.